# How to use HTTP POST method with in-memory web api and get updated object in response?

Tags: http, angular, service, http-post, in-memory

This is the object I am updating:

```
    {
      learning_node_id: 1001,
      status: 'EN',
      overall_progress: 78,
      difference: 2
    },
```

I am sending a POST request using a data service on a click event which is as follows:

```
getProgressDatabyId(nodeId: number, resourceStatus: string): Observable<IResourceProgress> {
    const url = `${this.progressUrl}/?learning_node_id=${nodeId}`;
    var json = JSON.stringify({progress_data : { status: resourceStatus }});
    return this.http.post(url, json, { headers: this.headers })
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

I am expecting response as following:

```
    {
      learning_node_id: 1001,
      status: 'CO',
      overall_progress: 78,
      difference: 2
    },
```

The response which I am getting is:
{
    id: 1,
    progress_data: {
        status: "CO";
    }
}

I am not able to understand why I am not able to get the exact updated object?

Comment: How does your this.extractData look like? Can you confirm the response using postman or any other rest client?

Comment: So this.extractData does nothing but simply gives res.json(). Cannot use postman I think as this is in-memory web api.